# Hide and show layout based on conditions in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, visibility

I am new to Android. I want to hide and show Linearlayout based on if else conditions. In my application I have taken 1 spinner. Based on selected spinner values I want my next layout hide or visible, but if it is once gone it not comes visible again.

My code is:

```
    public class Expense extends Activity{
    Spinner datype;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.expense);
    mainlayout=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    datype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.da_type);
    List<String>data1=new ArrayList<String>();
    data1.add("Local");
    data1.add("Ex-Station Double Side");
    data1.add("Ex-Station Single Side");
    data1.add("Out-Station Double Side");
    data1.add("Out-Station Single Side");
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
    datype.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(datype.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Local")){

        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
    else 
        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);


}

}
```

Comment: it is not working.....in my spinner first value is set by-default to "local". so layout is not visible. but when i select some other values from spinner. the layout is not comes in view... that is the problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `OnItemSelectedListener` and change your layout there too. Here is an example where your activity implements `OnItemSelectedListener`.

```
public class Expense extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private Spinner datype;
private LinearLayout mainlayout;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.expense);
    mainlayout=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    datype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.da_type);
    List<String>data1=new ArrayList<String>();
    data1.add("Local");
    data1.add("Ex-Station Double Side");
    data1.add("Ex-Station Single Side");
    data1.add("Out-Station Double Side");
    data1.add("Out-Station Single Side");
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
    datype.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(datype.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Local")){
        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
    else {
        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    } 

    // here we set the listener
    datatype.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // here we change layout visibility again
    if(datype.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Local")){
        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
    else {
        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    } 
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint into onItemSelected() and check it. What is the value of `datype.getSelectedItem()`?

Answer (score 8):

you can use this

instead

```
mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
```

of

```
mainlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

you have to hide and show your Code after click event of Spinner just this  **OnItemSelectedListener** method..

Comment: it is not working.....in my spinner first value is set by-default to "local". so layout is not visible. but when i select some other values from spinner. the layout is not comes in view... that is the problem

Answer (score 3):

*And also add*

> **android:visibility="visible"**

*in your* mainlayout *xml*.
*then use this*

> **mainlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);**

*in your  code*

Answer (score 2):

Instead of linear layout.gone try View.GONE

Answer (score 0):

rather than hiding the layout you can hide the entire view as below

```
  public class Expense extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private Spinner datype;
private LinearLayout mainlayout;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.expense);
    mainlayout=(LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    datype=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.da_type);
    List<String>data1=new ArrayList<String>();
    data1.add("Local");
    data1.add("Ex-Station Double Side");
    data1.add("Ex-Station Single Side");
    data1.add("Out-Station Double Side");
    data1.add("Out-Station Single Side");
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data1);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
    datype.setAdapter(adapter);
    if(datype.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Local")){
        mainlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        mainlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } 

    // here we set the listener
    datatype.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // here we change layout visibility again
    if(datype.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Local")){
        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    }
    else {
        mainlayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    } 
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
}
```